# Multiple api call in android retrofit

Tags: android, observable, rx-java, retrofit2

I am building an android application. In which in need to handle multiple api calls in queue to avoid collision using retrofit and also i need to manage this in common Applicationclass. It is possible?

Comment: You want to create a async or sync architecture ?

Comment: I need to handle multiple calls at a time.

Comment: Sync architecture on mobile... It is a very very bad practice @mrtcnkryln Never do that.

Comment: In volley there have a method `Volley.newRequestQueue()`. I need to use retrofit instead of volley. Is it available any direct method like this?

Comment: I dont mean general architecture. Im just talking event base situation. It can be two different service must works sequential. Maybe the question about it. I just want to learn detail of issue. I know what you say. @Aspicas

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using RxJava and Retrofit. RxJava provides us `zip` operator.
Sample code for this would be in your repository class

```
Observable.zip(
    getCricketFansObservable(),
    getFootballFansObservable(),
    BiFunction<List<User>, List<User>, List<User>> { cricketFans, footballFans ->
        // here we get both the results at a time.
        return@BiFunction filterUserWhoLovesBoth(cricketFans, footballFans)
    })
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe(getObserver())
```

Comment: how can i handle this in common class. means if network is on that time app call many api at a time. i need to handle this in one common class.

Comment: You can use a repository class have this logic written.

Comment: is it have any example